# Show partial previous and next item on PageTabViewStyle SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, pagetabviewstyle

I want PageTabViewStyle() to show me a little piece of the previous and next item.

I have code like this

```
var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0..<6) { _ in
            
                CustomButton()
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
```

Desired functionality here [image]

I tried GeometryReader but failed.